# Python split data and create variables/list of content (variable name + data)

Tags: python, python-2.6

I would like to split a string into many fields of data with an identical split separator.

```
data = ",0101,0202,03car,04bird"
print data.split(',')
```

then I would like to create a variable or list from each field.
example:

```
print string[01] 
result: 01
print string[02]
result: 02
print string[03]
result: car
print string[04]
result: bird
```

the data may come in a different order...

```
data = ",03box,08train"
```

and my need is to do a small loop to print

```
#NumberOfField = int(len(re.findall(',[0-9]+[0-9]', data)))
loop = 1 #loop start 
end = 8 #loop ends
while loop <= end: #a loop for x times
 stringvalue = loop.zfill(2) #to allways get 2 numbers in a string, example    01 
 print stringvalue+" - "+string[stringvalue]

wanted result:
01 - 
02 - 
03 - box
04 - 
05 - 
06 - 
07 - 
08 - train
```

I tried some different ideas, and I could do a 8 variable script, but the data may contain 50 to 200 fields.

Comment: What is your Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
import re

data = ",0101,0202,03car,04bird"
pat = re.compile(r'^(\d{2})(?!.*\1$)(.+)$')

res = {}
for s in data.split(','):
    matches = re.findall(pat, s)
    if len(matches) == 1:
        k, v = matches[0]
        res[k] = v

for i in range(1, 9):
    k = str(i).zfill(2)
    print k, '-', res.get(k, '')
    for i in range(1, 9):
        k = str(i).zfill(2)
        print k, '-', res.get(k, '')
```

Output:

```
01 - 
02 - 
03 - car
04 - bird
05 - 
06 - 
07 - 
08 -
```

Comment: wee, tnx, i testet it and this is coool . tnx so much Apero

Comment: would it be possible to use hex? or also 2 chars as the 2 first signs.?  for example: ",01car,FFbird"

Comment: I just improved my answer. Regarding your question, just replace (\d{2}) by any conditions you want to match.

Comment: tnx, Apero, your first ide worked like a charm... I having problems using hex. maybe thats a problem?  so if "data = ',03blurp,FFbird'" i would like to get the output: "03 - blurp + FF - bird" . (i see the \d{2} , but i am not soure what syntax to use :-)

Comment: maybe the output is tricking me :-) i changed the regex to (r'^(\d{2})([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\1$)(.+)$')

Comment: i changed re to "pat = re.compile(r'^([0-9a-zA-Z]{2})(?!.*\1$)(.+)$')" and now i can get "print '0A = '+res.get('0A', '')" working, nice.. i do have a problem that "0404" now working because of the re string. i have to read the "regex for dummies". anyway, tnx so mutch Apero you did the trick

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
d={}
for item in data.split(','):
    if not item:
        continue
    l = list(item)
    d[''.join(l[0:2])]=''.join(l[2:])
```

if you use a defaultdict for d, you can have missing keys as well

the problem with this approach is that it will fail if the "key" is not 2 digits/letters

Comment: testing now....  I was able to get it divided as expected. .. would it be possible to store it into strings/variables/lists ?  so i can later use "print string[03]" shows the value?

Answer (score 0):

So after some testing the script from Apero (tnx) is working 99,9%
I changed the regex to "pat = re.compile(r'^(\w{2})(.+)$')"
so if I do a:

```
data = ",03Y,04004,05005,0606,0A0A"
    print '04 = '+res.get('04', '')
    print '0A = '+res.get('0A', '')
```

I get:

```
   01 = 
   03 = Y
   04 = 004
   0A = 00A
```

the only issue now is...

```
if data = "data = ",03Y,0404,05005,0606,0A00A"
0404  and not 04004
the output is:
   01 = 
   03 = Y
   04 = 
   0A = 00A
```

as you can see all reg.ex that matches 0404 , 0505, 0606 etc is not matched correct.
if data = 04004, 05005, etc  its working.

Is there any tips to a working reg.ex
my wish is:

```
"data = ",03Y,0404,05005,0606,0A0A"
       01 = 
       03 = Y
       04 = 04
       0A = 0A
```

Comment: reg.ex was ok.. python script fault .. now its working .